# Does overriding a checkout discard changes or save changes?

Tags: document, check-out, checklist

When I go to checkout out a file, sometimes a previous user has forgotten to check the file back in and I have the option to override their checkout. When doing that, are the changes the previous user made saved or discarded?

Comment: The changes do get saved if you have permission to override.
Just tried in 2013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overriding checkout will remove the lock and assign the checkout user data to your name.

Nothing will get Saved/Discarded (These changes are available in the previously checked out user's computer).

You risk losing any changes made by previous user that were not saved.